# Spring-security shows 'Bad Credentials' even before submitting the form

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have following code for spring security but it does not work. When I open log-in page and enter username/password which is admin@myproject.com / secret, following error message will be shown. Once username/password are entered following with be added to the address `?error=1`, even if I remove it manually and refresh the page message does not go. Nothing is shown in console.

```
Your login attempt was not successful due to

Bad credentials.
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">



    <beans:import resource='login-service.xml' />
    <http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/notFound.jsp"
        use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/member**" access="hasRole('ROLE_MEMBER')" />
        <form-login login-page="/signin" default-target-url="/index"
            authentication-failure-url="/signin?error=1" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <csrf />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service> <user name="admin@myproject.com" password="secret" 
                authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/> 
            <user name="user@yahoo.com" password="secret" authorities="ROLE_USER"/> 
                </user-service> 

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

The form has following code, it seems like `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION`is not empty even before submitting the form.

```
<c:if test="${not empty SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION}">
            <font color="red"> Your login attempt was not successful due
                to <br />
            <br /> <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />.
            </font>
        </c:if>
            <form id="form-login" role="form" method="post"
                        action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />"
                        class="relative form form-default">
                        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                            value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

I am not sure why, but the same code returns following error now

```
Your login attempt was not successful due to

Authentication method not supported: GET.
```

Comment: I noticed that your access denied page is the `/notFound.jsp` - so are you really sure that you have an access-denied-problem, but not a resource-not-found-problem?

Comment: @Ralph I am not sure, it is showing the page with the error message. I am not sure what the issue is

Comment: First create an separate access denied page, and then you can configure them in `spring-security:http`  tag

Comment: what do you mean by separate access denied page?

Comment: can you add some more relevant lines from the log? Have you specified any error pages in web.xml?

Comment: @tharindu_DG nothing is shown in the console.

Comment: Have you tried changing /signin to /signin** , plus, how are you resolving the password? does your password input has "password" as name?

Answer (score 5):

You need to allow everyone to access your `/signin` page, even if he is not authenticated.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/signin" access="permitAll" />
```

*I wrote this answer before the question was changed the first time, at a time where the question was (it is still the title): "Spring-security shows 'Bad Credentials' even before submitting the form"*

Answer (score 3):

```
<intercept-url pattern="/member**" access="hasRole('ROLE_MEMBER')" />


<user name="user@yahoo.com" password="secret" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
```

Above configs have two different Role names **ROLE_MEMBER** and **ROLE_USER**

**UPDATE**

Since `Authentication method not supported: GET`, can you try allowing `GET`.

```
<bean id="authenticationFilter" 
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
      p:postOnly="false" />
```

And the following change is also required in `web.xml`

```
<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I thought that the request is rejected because of the url could not be resolved. Did it work?

Comment: no when I click on the link it goes to /signin?error=1 thats weird!

Comment: I am using my code again but it shows following Your login attempt was not successful due to

Authentication method not supported: GET.

Comment: I set them as permitAll exactly like what is in the question

Answer (score 2):

The `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION` stays in the session even if you refresh the page. You need check for the `error` parameter:

```xml
<c:if test="${(not empty param.error) && (not empty SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION)}">
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your login controller method is doing `redirect` or `forward`, and then tries to send a `HTTP GET` request to the login URL with the user name and password as query parameters. It is generally considered bad practice to send credentials as URL parameters and that's why is not allowed. It be should send a `HTTP POST` instead.
If you will want to stay with `GET`, you could bypass the check by using a request wrapper which returns `HTTP POST` instead of `HTTP GET` for `getMethod`.

Updated answer from @tharingu_DG should work, but it is still technically equivalent to sending unencrypted authentication credentials since anyone who steals it can use it to authenticate.